# is CI_MERGE_REQUEST_LABELS still usable after merge request is merged

Tags: bash, shell, gitlab-ci

Is this variable `CI_MERGE_REQUEST_LABELS` still usable once the merge request is merged ? I want to execute a pipeline and use the labels of the merge request **after** it's merged.

```
rules:
    - if: '$CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME == "master"'
  script: |
    #!/bin/bash
    
    # If one of the labels of the merge request is 'rollback'
    if [[ "$CI_MERGE_REQUEST_LABELS" == *"rollback"* ]]; then
      ...
    fi
```